# Is it possible to declare a form object inside a block of if condition in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am very new to zend framework. I want to declare a form object inside an if condition. but I don't know is it possible or not ?. I write the below code:

```
public function editAction()
    {
        $modelUsers = new Model_Users();
        $userId = $this->_getParam('userId');

        if ($userId) {

            $populateData = array();

            $user = $modelUsers->fetch($userId);
        //  print_r($user); exit();

                if ($user instanceof Model_User) {
                    $populateData = $user->toArray();
                                    $form = $this->_geteditForm($user->email);
                }

                $form->populate($populateData);
            }

            $request = $this->getRequest();

            if ($request->isPost()) {
```

Please let me know I am going to the write path or not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK, but (assuming that it's some kind of a crud) it's better to redirect back to list or throw exception if the ID is missing. Than you don't need to close the whole form in condition. i.e:

```
if (!$userId = $this->_getParam('userId')) {
    throw new Exception('Missing userId');
    //or
    $this->_helper->redirector('index');
}
```